# Numerical search in Apache lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene Search works well with the application but the only issue is how should i search the result depending upon various conditions (AND,OR)

```
My Scenario:
```

I am searching the product details through the lucene and it's working fine but i do have various Drop-down filters according to which i need to show results

```
I found TermQuery, BooleanQuery, ConstantScoreQuery, MatchAllDocsQuery,
MultiPhraseQuery, FuzzyQuery, WildcardQuery, RangeQuery, PrefixQuery,
PhraseQuery are the options available
```

But i actually don't understand how should i apply this to my Scenario (i.e how should i append the selected value of dropdown filters to the Search Query)
as well as please guide me the way to search the numeric value with lucene
is it possible with lucene or should i go to solr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say initial query is field1:value1 AND field2:value2. Now user selects a value (value3) from dropdown (which corresponds to field3), just expand the query by appending field3:value3 to initial query.

Initial query:

```
field1:value1 field2:value2
```

Query after user selects a value from dropdown:

```
field1:value1 field2:value2 field3:value3
```

About searching for numeric values: How are these numbers indexed? Is there a separate field that contains just numbers? Or are these numbers part of normal text?

UPDATE (based on op's reply that numeric values are indexed (and stored) as Int fields)

you can use NumericRangeQuery to query on numeric fields. For equality queries give upper and lower bound as the same value. Go through http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SearchNumericalFields

Comment: The Numbers are indexed as Field pIdField = new IntField("p_id", pid, Field.Store.YES);
document.add(nuggetIdField); and there is separate field that contains numbers